# Attempting to build (NFT) transaction in Python and push through Cardano-cli

Tags: transaction, nft, python

[image]

right now I am getting the system can't find the path specified but I have tried with and without passing the path in as a variable.

I am running this in Python 3.6+ in Visual Studio Code on Windows.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use a Python library (like Pycardano) for building transactions?

Comment: I know there are other libaries, but I am looking to build from ground up just to understand the process.